# Фамилия Макась в родительном падеже

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Как будет Максим Макась в родительном падеже?

Answer (score 1):

"Макася (Максима)". В женском варианте - "Макась (Елены)" (не склоняется).

Answer (score 0):

Склоняется фамилия "Макась", если она принадлежит мужчине, в данном случае это Максим. И не склонялась бы, если бы принадлежала женщине, например Ирине. Таким образом, Макася Максима (в род. п.) - склоняется, 
Макась Ирины - не склоняется.